# Win32 - Intercept keyboard sleep button

Tags: winapi

Every keyboard action can be caught with SetWindowsHookEx(), but not the sleep button. You can set it to "Do nothing" in the control panel, but I want to do something useful with it. Is this possible? (I'm using a Das Keyboard 4 Professional).

Answer (score 2):

[This old MSDN page](https://web.archive.org/web/20020202115706/http://www.microsoft.com/hwdev/tech/input/Scancode.asp) lists the scan codes for the power action keys:

> The following defines the correct scan codes for keyboard power switches for OnNow hardware:
>
> ```
> Power event 
>  Set1:    Make = E0, 5E    Break = E0, DE
>  Set2:    Make = E0, 37    Break = E0, F0, 37
>
> Sleep event 
>  Set1:    Make = E0, 5F    Break = E0, DF
>  Set2:    Make = E0, 3F    Break = E0, F0, 3F
>
> Wake event 
>  Set1:    Make = E0, 63    Break = E0, E3
>  Set2:    Make = E0, 5E    Break = E0, F0, 5E
> ```
>
> The Set 2 break codes also need the 0xE0 prefix, otherwise the system will see the new key going down but see some different key coming up.

but if you look at the [USB HID tables](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf) there is something called "Power Controls"

> Power controls can step the system through the following states: Full Power, Low Power, and Power Down
>
> Power control usages found in a 
>   System Control
>    collection affect system 
>   level power.
>
> System Sleep 
>   OSC – Asserted when the intended action is to initiate system-wide low 
>   power mode now. If the system is already in the Low Power state, there is no 
>   effect.

so it is possible that the keyboard is using the USB protocol directly to sleep.